# Access @store arguments in "create policy"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a route like this in `routes/api.php`:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {

    Route::post('messages/{pet}', 'MessageController@store')->middleware('can:create,message');

});
```

We see here that it has implicit `{pet}`.

My controller accesses `{pet}` just fine like this:

`app\Http\Controllers\MessageController.php`:

```
public function store(Request $request, Pet $pet)
{
    dd($pet);
}
```

I want to my `->middleware('can:create,message')` to get the arguments of `store` seen here, so I want `$request` and `$pet`, is this possible?

Here is my current `MessagePolicy@create` but its not getting the arguments I expect:

`app\Policies\MessagePolicy.php`

```
public function create(User $user, Request $request, Pet $pet)
{
    dd($request); // dd($pet);
    return $user->can('view', $pet) && ($request->input('kind') == null|| $request->input('kind') == 'PLAIN');
}
```

Also `dd` is not working for some reason.

Comment: Hi for this example is the user try to create a message or a pet ?

Comment: Thanks very much @Maraboc! yep a I create a pet on message, when message has body like "Create pet 'Simba'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want create a Pet for a given message, in this case the [implicit model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#implicit-binding) will not work here because the pet not yet created so finding a pet by the given id will always return null.

In this case laravel offer the possibility to use Actions That Don't Require Models (see [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#authorizing-actions-using-policies) -> Via Middleware section)

> Again, some actions like create may not require a model instance. In
>   these situations, you may pass a class name to the middleware. The
>   class name will be used to determine which policy to use when
>   authorizing the action

---

So in your case :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {

    Route::post('messages/{pet}', 'MessageController@store')->middleware('can:create,App\Pet');

});
```

And in the **PetPolicy** you can use the request() helper method :

```
public function create(User $user)
{
    return request('kind') == null|| request('kind') == 'PLAIN';
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much for your awesome help. This is really cool. I even understand the docs now. I'm pretty new to Laravel so am still learning how to read the docs. I noticed this is calling the `create` of PetPolicy, if we used `$this->authorize('create', $message->pet)` in `MessageController@store` would this call the `create` of `MessagePolicy`? I tried this now and i think it is but I'm not able to `dd` so I'm not able to verify 100%.

Comment: It's the same thing if you want to create a Pet you can do `$this->authorize('create', Pet::class);` for the message `$this->authorize('create', Message::class);` this way you tel Laravel i want this exact policy.

Comment: Superb thank you sir! It seems I am able to do this inside `MessageController@store`: `$message = new Message([......]); $message->pet_id = $pet->id; $this->authorize('create', $message)`. Then in `MessagePolicy@create` I am able to get `$pet` from the relationship `$message->pet()`!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the **request()** helper method.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-request

Comment: Thanks Andrei but I dont understand. I think `$request` is already available as 2nd argument no?

Answer (score 0):

The `$request` have a method `has()` for determining if a value is present ([Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#retrieving-input)).
You can alter your method to check if the value exists or its equals to `"PLAIN"`

```
public function create(User $user, Request $request)
{
    return !$request->has('kind') || $request->input('kind') == 'PLAIN';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andre but I don't think this is the problem. I tried it and it didn't fix it. :( Here is my policy php file - https://gist.githubusercontent.com/blagoh/72c394d1d2b129a414fb15363fa8ee00/raw/ded0a4b15e7ed060e3c67c8b06147d05e324e46a/MessagePolicy.php

Answer (score 0):

use

```
return ( $request->has('kind') )? $request->has('kind') && $request->input('kind') === 'PLAIN': true;
```

Comment: Thanks Srinath but I also want to accept it, if it does NOT have a `kind`. :(

Comment: Thank you sir, but it doesn't work. :( I am thinking the `$request` argument is null and error is not throwing.