# Use relationship with policy of another model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel v5.5.14.

I have an endpoint, for `App\Message` in `routes/api.php`:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {

    Route::put('messages/{message}', 'MessageController@update')->middleware('can:view,pet');

});
```

I want to apply the policy of `can:view,pet` which is defined in my `PetPolicy.php` here:

```
namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Pet;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class PetPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function view(User $user, Pet $pet)
    {
        return $user->pets()->where('pet_id', $pet->id)->exists();
    }
}
```

Every `App\Message` has a `App\Pet` I declare that pets have many messages (one-to-many) relationship in my models. And every `App\User` can have many `App\Pet` so many-to-many.

`app/Pet.php`:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pet extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function messages()
    {
        // one-to-many hasMany belongsTo
        return $this->hasMany('App\Message');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        // many-to-many belongsToMany "
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

`app/Message.php`:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Message extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['body', 'kind'];

    public function pet()
    {
        // one-to-many hasMany belongsTo
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Pet');
    }
}
```

`app/User.php`:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    // ....

    public function pets()
    {
        // many-to-many belongsToMany "
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Pet');
    }    

    public function messages()
    {
        // one-to-many hasMany belongsTo
        return $this->hasMany('App\Message');
    }
}
```

However my policy is failing, it is always giving unauthorized. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

This is my `app/AuthServiceProvider.php`:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Pet' => 'App\Policies\PetPolicy',
        'App\Message' => 'App\Policies\MessagePolicy'
    ];

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: can you show us the `protected $policies` of the `AuthServiceProvider` ??

Comment: There is no problem in there, one more thing you didn't mention the relation between user and Pets !!

Comment: Ah thank you @Maraboc the relation there is many-to-many. I will edit it in above and update you.

Comment: @Maraboc thanks very much sir for your patience and help I just added it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test it with this query :

```
namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Pet;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class PetPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function view(User $user, Pet $pet)
    {
        return User::where('id', $user->id)
                    ->whereHas('pets', function ($query) use($pet) {
                            $query->where('id', $pet->id);
                        })
                    ->exists();
    }
}
```

Or just like this if you want :

```
return $user->pets->contains($pet->id);
```

Or like this :

```
return DB::table('pet_user')
    ->whereUserId($user->id)
    ->wherePetId($pet->id)
    ->count() > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks very much at Maraboc for this help, I think this is not the problem though because I use it succesfully on another endpoint. I tried all of your tries and that other endpoint works (`/pets/{pet}`) but this one is not. Is it because the second arg in `PetPolicy` is expecting `Pet` and it is probably getting `Message` as my url is `/messages/{message}` instead of `/messages/{pet}`?

Comment: Yes i forgot to check it first in this case you should work with message not pet !!

Comment: Ahh thanks @Maraboc, there is no way to reuse that endpint by like somehow making 2nd argument be either Pet or Message?

Comment: And with the MessagePolicy and if you stil want check the pet you can do it like this `return DB::table('pet_user')
    ->whereUserId($user->id)
    ->wherePetId($message->pet->id)
    ->count() > 0;`

Comment: and the same for the other cases replace `pet` with `$message->pet` ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Because of you being by my side it pushed me to learn in fast time! :)

Comment: Quick question related to this please. For my route `Route::post('messages/{pet}', 'MessageController@store')->middleware('can:create,message');` then the 2nd argument to PetPolicy@create would be the arguments that go to `store` correct? So my `PetPolicy@create` would be: `create(User $user, Request $request, Pet $pet)`? I tried this but its not working it seems.

Comment: I rephrased my question here, I think it is the exact same thing, I am not getting the argumetns I expect - https://stackoverflow.com/q/46777395/3791822 - may you please take a look if you have some time sir? :)

Comment: @Maniruzzaman happy to help, and i'm ready to help any time ;)